# How to refresh footer view in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have created a view (xib) as my footer.

I have assigned the file owner of the xib to `FTHeaderFooterViewController`.

I have definied a pointer called `total` to my label, where `footerView` points to my actual footer view.

```
    @interface FTHeaderFooterViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        IBOutlet UIView *footerView;

        __weak IBOutlet UILabel *total;
    }
    - (UIView *)footerView;

@implementation FTHeaderFooterViewController

-(UIView *)footerView
{
    if (!footerView) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FTFooterView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return footerView;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self footerView] bounds].size.height;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self footerView];
}
```

That all works fine the footer shows.

However when I change the value for a label in :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self drawFooter];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)drawFooter
{
    NSString *totalStr = @"test";
    [total setText:totalStr];
}
```

The label doesn't get refreshed. What am I missing?

Comment: darn..yes you are right. But where do I initialise the label? in xib or code behind?

Comment: Did you link your UILabel to your xib ? Because normally the xib should initialize your UILabel

Comment: @AncAinu that is a good pointer.  I use my own `init` to construct the viewController. Maybe that causes the problem...

Comment: If you use a xib, the standard `init` methods isn't called (in my memories, I don't use xib), it should be `initWithNibName...`, so you should override and use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Things:

1.
You forgot to assign the footerview variable when you load the xib file

```
-(UIView *)footerView
{
    if (!footerView) {
        footerView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FTFooterView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return footerView;
}
```

2.
 Your footerview method overrides default getter from the footerview IBOutlet property

```
-(UIView *)footerView
```

Comment: ahhh the problem is not 2. I was intending to override the getter to return the code from 1.  The problem was 1. itself. Thanks for the hint!  I had to run `[self footerView];` in the init to make sure the view is set and its not `nil`, before `viewWillApear` tries to set the label's text.